# How to use nav2_simple_commander in foxy?

Tags: turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html#overview to create a simple demo application using navigation2 (the simple commander API looks really cool for a simple demo application, BTW).
However I am unable to find the simple commander package in foxy. The `foxy-devel` branch at https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/foxy-devel does not even have the corresponding directory for `nav2_simple_commander`.

What should I install to get `nav2_simple_commander.py` in foxy or alternatively what API/tutorial should I use to implement a simple example that sets the initial pose estimate for a turtlebot and then navigates to a fixed goal point in Python?

Incidentally, I tried to work in galactic, where the package for the simple commander appears to exist - but there I run into troubles of being unable to get the turtlebot3 simulation packages for webots to work (I guess some other packages wait for release).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392682/how-to-use-nav2_simple_commander-in-foxy?/) by [Andrzej Wasowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29731/andrzej-wasowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind. I used this example from Steve: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2283#issuecomment-853456150 (which seems to be an early draft of `nav2_simple_commander`). I only used the tiny part I needed to navigate to the initial pose.  I presume that the simple commander was only implemented for galactic, so future users will be able to use it (it seems great!).

---

Originally posted by [Andrzej Wasowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29731/andrzej-wasowski/) with karma: 36 on 2021-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nartmangnourt](https://answers.ros.org/users/143866/nartmangnourt/) on 2023-06-15**:
Hey Andrzej,

i want to use the simple commander for foxy too. I executed the node from Steve: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2283#issuecomment-853456150

But gettting this output:

```
[INFO] [1686824312.587229383] [basic_navigator]: Publishing Initial Pose
[INFO] [1686824314.598953296] [basic_navigator]: Setting initial pose
[INFO] [1686824314.600323862] [basic_navigator]: Publishing Initial Pose
[INFO] [1686824314.601619469] [basic_navigator]: Waiting for amcl_pose to be received
[INFO] [1686824314.602949965] [basic_navigator]: Setting initial pose
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thank you so much :)